# Number of sessions with node.js/express for a game

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, session

I want to create a choice-based text adventure game using Node.js/Express/Passport with the client side being HTML5 with jQuery. To provide a better understanding of what I want, here's how the game works so far:

- The client's browser sends a JSON object to the server via jQuery to set up a new game.
- The server starts a new Express session and sends a JSON object with the scene text and choice button data.
- The client clicks on a choice, sending the a JSON object to the server with information such as what scene to call next, etc.

This keeps going through-out the game and every so often the server will access the session data to modify the player's inventory, health, etc.

If I want the game to be able to support hundreds of players at once, how would I get Express to handle that many sessions at once? My main concern is overall speed of the node.js server, as well as RAM usage.

Comment: Why not just try it and see for yourself? It shouldn't be hard to simulate that.

Comment: I'm sure any test like this would work if you throw enough CPU speed and RAM at it, but I'm more concerned about the _right_ way to do it. I can't seem to find any documentation about the right way to handle hundreds of sessions.

Comment: Well, that's a different question than what you originally posed. How do you know the solutions you found are "wrong" if you haven't tried them yet?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question. Most of the solutions I've found talk about horizontal and vertical scaling, I haven't come across anything that describes the correct way to handle lots of session data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100s is not lots :)  At that volume, you probably don't need to give this a ton of special consideration - see if you have a problem before solving it.  File I/O would likely to be the main bottleneck here so keep the global game data cached in memory as much as possible.  If you do find you are hitting scale issues, start by using the node `cluster` module to leverage multiple CPUs on the same machine... if that still isn't enough, you'd run your node code on multiple servers and stick a load balancer in front of them.  Key to scaling is storing session state in a database that any server can access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've looked into keeping session data in a database and I'm going to try out Passport with MongoDB.